# React router dom v5 default route doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react router dom v5 with material ui, and I have my routes in the following way:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Login from '../screens/Login'
import NotFound from '../screens/NotFound'
import routes from './routes'

const DynamicRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {Object.values(routes).map(({ component, path }) => (
        <Route exact path={path} key={path} component={component} />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Layout>
          <DynamicRoutes />
        </Layout>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Router
```

I have already tried with `<Route component={NotFound} />`, and neither worked to me. Can anyone help me? The rest of routes work correctly, but when I type a fake route, doesn't go to the `NotFound` screen.

Comment: Hello, this looks like an interesting question to me. Thanks for sharing the solutions you already tried. My guess is that when you try the 'fake route' you actually do not type or mechanically redirect, but you try it from your `Layout` component by trying to redirect it inside the component. Am I right?

Comment: Hi @GiorgiGvimradze, I'm in one of my defined routes, that is inside of the ```Layout``` component, and I want to load the ```NotFound``` component from there. 
Imagine that I'm on a route named ```/home```, that is inside of the ```Layout```, and then you type on the url ```/home/random-text```, then I don't get redirected to the ```NotFound``` screen. What could I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69162456/default-route-always-execute-in-react-router. Can anyone answer this question also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That occurs because all children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements.
You can check more about it in react-router-dom [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch/children-node).

So, one solution for your code would be do something like that:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        {Object.values(routes).map(({ Component, path }) => (
          <Route exact path={path} key={path}>
            <Layout>
              <Component />
            </Layout>
          </Route>
        ))}
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

*For your routes object array, Component property must be with an upper `C`.

You can check this [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-sample-e3znx) code.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation , it works now, so the problem was that the children of the ```Switch``` was another component instead ```Route```

Comment: Hi @rubenmondom, yes, that´s right! *My sample code was with a wrong link. I just corrected it, sorry.

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto Can you please answer my question also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69162456/default-route-always-execute-in-react-router