# Default route always execute in react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a project where I am using the strikingDash template. Here I face some issues of routing while changing the routes from URL.

auth.js

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react"
import { Spin } from "antd"
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import AuthLayout from "../container/profile/authentication/Index"

const Login = lazy(() =>
  import("../container/profile/authentication/overview/SignIn")
)
const SignUp = lazy(() =>
  import("../container/profile/authentication/overview/SignUp")
)
const ForgetPassword = lazy(() =>
  import("../container/profile/authentication/overview/ForgetPassword")
)
const EmailConfirmation = lazy(() =>
  import("../container/profile/authentication/overview/EmailConfirmation")
)
const VerificationPage = lazy(() =>
  import("../container/profile/authentication/overview/VerificationPage")
)

const NotFound = () => {
  console.log("NOT FOUND")
  return <Redirect to="/" />
}

const FrontendRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Suspense
        fallback={
          <div className="spin">
            <Spin />
          </div>
        }
      >
        <Route exact path="/verification" component={VerificationPage} />
        <Route exact path="/email-confirmation" component={EmailConfirmation} />
        <Route exact path="/forgetPassword" component={ForgetPassword} />
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Suspense>
    </Switch>
  )
}

export default AuthLayout(FrontendRoutes)
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { hot } from "react-hot-loader/root";
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ConfigProvider } from "antd";
import store from "./redux/store";
import Admin from "./routes/admin";
import Auth from "./routes/auth";
import "./static/css/style.css";
import config from "./config/config";
import ProtectedRoute from "./components/utilities/protectedRoute";

const { theme } = config;

const ProviderConfig = () => {
  const { rtl, isLoggedIn, topMenu, darkMode } = useSelector(state => {
    return {
      darkMode: state.ChangeLayoutMode.data,
      rtl: state.ChangeLayoutMode.rtlData,
      topMenu: state.ChangeLayoutMode.topMenu,
      isLoggedIn: state.Authentication.login,
    };
  });

  const [path, setPath] = useState(window.location.pathname);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unmounted = false;
    if (!unmounted) {
      setPath(window.location.pathname);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-return-assign
    return () => (unmounted = true);
  }, [setPath]);

  return (
    <ConfigProvider direction={rtl ? "rtl" : "ltr"}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={{ ...theme, rtl, topMenu, darkMode }}>
        <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
          {!isLoggedIn ? <>{console.log("INSIDE PUBLIC")}<Route path="/" component={Auth} /></> : <ProtectedRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} />}
          {isLoggedIn && (path === process.env.PUBLIC_URL || path === `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`) && (
            <Redirect to="/admin" />
          )}
        </Router>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ProviderConfig />
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default hot(App);
```

Whenever I change the URL to another route as I described above in Frontend Routes. Then it will always print console statements like these:

```
INSIDE PUBLIC
NOT FOUND
INSIDE PUBLIC
NOT FOUND
```

Expected Behaviour: Whenever I update the URL it will render the component according to the switch case and return it back

Actual Behaviour: Whenever I update the URL it will render the component as well as the default component. I think Switch here renders multiple components, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just resolved the issue by moving the `Switch` Tag inside the `Suspense` tag in the auth.js file.

Comment: Hi Hassam, I've just seen your question and looks like you already found the solution. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your reply @LuisPauloPinto. Can you please explain to me how to do it generically for all routes? I found the solution only for auth routes.

Comment: i really don't know how to help you with this, i would need to do a sample code to check it, but i'm out of time at the moment. Is there nothing in the reactjs docs?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto can you please share your email. I will send you a sample code

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be in the order of your pages: the root path works as a collector of all the pages, you should try to add the `exact` keyword to the Router path. Here the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162311/react-difference-between-route-exact-path-and-route-path) for the differences between the different notations.

```js
<Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
```